# How to use analogWrite() on multiple pins at the same time?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, pins

I would like to do,

`analogWrite(100,3);
 analogWrite(200,6);`

at the same time. But the problem is that only the led on pin 3 lights up. I want both to light up at the same time. I've heard about direct port manipulation, but I can only find an alternate for `digitalWrite()` but I couldn't find one for `analogWrite()`. Can someone please help me with just a simple example on just how to do the above operation?

I'm using arduino uno.

Answer (score 11):

You have your parameters the wrong way round:

```
analogWrite(2, 100);
analogWrite(6, 200);
```

**However**: pin 2 on the Uno cannot do PWM, so you will have to pick a different pin. Look for the pins marked with `~` - they are the PWM pins. On the Uno that is pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10 and 11.

Comment: yeah I'm sorry it's pin 3. Now how to i turn both on at the same time?

Comment: Just like that. When you run `analogWrite()` it starts PWM on that pin and it *keeps going until you tell it otherwise*. If you aren't getting anything out then you have probably broken that pin through misuse or doing something else in your code that's stopping PWM.

Comment: No. if i use pin 6 first, then pin 3. The pin 6 lights up and not pin 3

Comment: And if you do it the other way around? And NOT PIN 2.

Comment: analogWrite(6, 100);
analogWrite(3, 200); This turns on pin 6

Comment: ***NOT PIN 2***

Comment: I think you have blown the LED on pin **3**.  You haven't said that you have a resistor between the LEDs and the Uno.  If this is the case you might have fried the LED on pin 3.  If its good then try doing (3, 100) not 200 and see if that works.

Comment: I guess someone has to introduce multiplexing here...